# adding integers together in a function

Tags: flutter, dart

I have three ints that change as the user uses the app. i'm trying to set up a function that adds them together passively in the background and outputs a to another int that i've created. so i can then use it in an if else statement down the line to check if it is greater or less than another int. I can set it to work when the user presss a button, but is there a way to do it passivly?  here is my function:

```
int calculateLeftTotalVP(){return movpLeftCounter + totalTOLeftCounter + paintedLeftCounter = totalVPLeft;}
```

I'm getting the error: Missing selector such as '.identifier' or '[0]'.  Try adding a selector.

under the 3 ints i'm trying to add together.

what would be the best way to go about this please? cheers

Answer (score 0):

I think you want like this

```dart
int calculateLeftTotalVP() {
  return totalVPLeft =
      movpLeftCounter + totalTOLeftCounter + paintedLeftCounter;
}
```

I would prefer passing variable and then return the result from it.

```dart
int calculateLeftTotalVP({
  required int movpLeftCounter,
  required int totalTOLeftCounter,
  required int paintedLeftCounter,
}) {
  return movpLeftCounter + totalTOLeftCounter + paintedLeftCounter;
}

totalVPLeft = calculateLeftTotalVP(movpLeftCounter: ,paintedLeftCounter: ,totalTOLeftCounter: );
```

Comment: hi, thanks so much for the help. when using the second one, there are a couple of errors.

Comment: You need to pass value on second one like `calculateLeftTotalVP(movpLeftCounter: 12,` Do you get others kind of issue ?

Comment: first there the error: Variables must be declared using the keywords 'const', 'final', 'var' or a type name. on the bottom totalVPLeft, so i put int in front of it and the second error is the bottom calculateLeftTotalVP is giving the error: The instance member 'calculateLeftTotalVP' can't be accessed in an initializer

Comment: Can you include full sample code, I need to check how and where you are using this

Comment: the first version seems to be working but how would i then use it in a string or if else statement? e.g. '$totalVPLeft/20'

Comment: if you like to perform arithmetic operation and present on string format, you can do `${totalVPLeft/20}`. Also `(totalVPLeft/20).toString()` will work